# How to Split a String on mathematical operators as delimiters but escape operators inside quotes (in java)?

Tags: java, regex

For example,

`AM2 + 'G - D08 - 28 - 14 .xlsx]General Inputs'`
should be split as

`AM2` and `'G - D08 - 28 - 14 .xlsx]General Inputs'`.

Answer (score 1):

For your type of given input example, I would probably match vs splitting.

```
String s  = "AM2 + 'G - D08 - 28 - 14 .xlsx]General Inputs'";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'[^']*'|[^ '+*/-]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output

```
AM2
'G - D08 - 28 - 14 .xlsx]General Inputs'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with `split`--if you can, it would be very tricky and messy.  `split` is good at looking for delimiters, but not so good when a pattern has to be applied to the stuff in between delimiters, which it would in this case.

Instead, I'd use a regex to look for the text that occurs *between* delimiters, and use the `Matcher` methods.  The way I look at problems like this is to think of the non-operator text as a sequence of entities, where each entity is

- a quoted string;
- a single character that is not a quote, and is not an operator (or the start of an operator, if some operators are two or more characters).

If all your operators are one character, a regex that finds an "operand" might look like

```
('.*?'|[^'+\-*/])*
```

which says to look for any number of characters between quote marks, *or* for any single character that is not `+`, `-`, `*`, or `/` (note that the `-` has to be escaped inside the character class).  The last `*` means to look for zero or more of this pattern.

To look for a case where an operator might be multiple characters, such as `<<` or `>>`, you can use negative lookahead:

```
('.*?'|(?!\+|-|\*|/|<<|>>)[^'])*
```

which means to find either a quoted string, or a non-quote character at a point where we're not looking at `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `<<`, or `>>`, and find this zero or more times.

The plan would be to use `lookingAt()` with a matcher to find the operand, then use `lookingAt()` to find the operator, and go back and forth.  (Or if you don't need to keep the operators at all, use `find()` as in @hwnd's answer.)

**NOTE: I have not tested this.**  I may have some details wrong, but this should give you an idea of the best approach.

Comment: (+1) Good detailed answer. You could change your lookahead to use a character class `(?![+/*-]|<<|>>)`